# Opencv make error

Tags: opencv

I see this during make opencv:
I download source for opencv git

```
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 22%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 22%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o
/home/fhwa/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp: In function ‘bool mjpeg_to_rgb24(int, int, unsigned char*, int, unsigned char*)’:
/home/fhwa/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp:1740:16: error: ‘imdecode’ is not a member of ‘cv’
   cv::Mat temp=cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(std::vector<uchar>(src, src + length)), 1);
                ^
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

any hint? do I miss some packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a stable version

> wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip/download

not cutting-edge version(from git)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use plhn solution, or do `git checkout` on latest stable tag:

```
$git tag -l #list all tags
$git checkout 2.4.9 #thats the latest stable version
```

This will checkout the same version as in latest stable packages. But as a bonus, You can look into the sourcecode if some not clear exceptions appear.